# detect mis-configured spring bean wiring at compile time

Tags: java, spring, compilation

Is there a way or a tool that can, at compile time, detect if any of my spring beans have not been autowired correctly.

For e.g., for type based wiring, it should complain if that type does not exist. Or for 'name' based wiring, it should complain if a bean by that name does not exist.

These can be caught at application start time, but that sounds too late in the game (especially when you have a long deployment process).

Comment: Some focused Spring Tests also should bring out any wiring issues, wanted to make a point that we need not wait until application start up time to find wiring issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) [does a great job](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/spring_framework.html) of figuring out incorrect mappings in XML and in classes. I guess [sts-springsourcetoolsuite](/questions/tagged/sts-springsourcetoolsuite) has similar features.

But the best safety net for you is simply writing an integration test starting up the whole context and running it in continuous integration.

Comment: i think they do provide code completion to a great extent, but not exactly what I'm looking for (unless i'm missing something).

Comment: @Saket: apart from code completion your XML turns red when you try to use non-existing bean. The same applies for Java classes - autowired fields are marked red if no such beans exists (or more than one)